# lighttpd rewrite script running on port to same domain for XSS?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I am running freeNAS7 / lighttpd with some perl scripts that run on various ports localhost:5000, or localhost:8080 for example.

Now i tried to add cross-domian policy to the header but i cant get it to work, because most likley I am doing it incorrectly.I am not familiar with perl, if it were PHP then its pretty easy adding a header.(in terms of me understaning where to put it)

I was just thinking is there a way to rewrite for example something like

localhost/sabnzdb  to display localhost:8080/ so that i can use client side to manipulate the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lighttpd it's possible through mod_redirect. You can read about it [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModRewrite).
`url.redirect = ( "^/sabnzdb$" => "http://localhost:8080" )`
and put that in your localhost vhost (if you use vhosts) otherwise any place in your config should be ok.